# How can I sort RawContacts by their display name?

Tags: android, sorting, rawcontacts

I need to read all contacts that belong to a specific account and sort them by their name.

And I would like to get them sorted in the `Cursor` rather then sort them after in an array.

This is what I currently do:

1. I make a query in `ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI` and get their `ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID`
2. make another query after it's data in `ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY` based on the id
   and
3. add it to an array.
   (it doesn't seem a great solution but I don't know about any other way to achieve this)

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems there is no way to do this using a simple query. Since 4 years there has been no evolution in this archaic system.

Answer (score 0):

Run query like this

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
   ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1", 
   null, 
   "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Now cursor retrun shoted value

Comment: Thanks for your impressively quick response, but I mentioned in the title that I'm looking for RawContacts (that belong to a specific account)

Comment: elaborate more please

Comment: ContactsContract.RawContacts table, not ContactsContract.Contacts table